# match letters a to z in a enum type as if were in a flexer file

Tags: c#, regex

Moring,

I just wanna whatever string to fit in my enum type defined, as if were in a flexer file and i'm struggling with that , hope you guys can help me. 
this is an example of the issue i wanna resolve.

```
enum Token 
{
    AND = '^',
    OR =  'V', 
    string = -- here is when im struggling
}
```

since in a flexer file is just like this  `[a-z]*` and you can match any string with it,  but I'm not using  flex. I already achieved it with only special characters as showed in the example. 
But don't know if there is an approach to achieve it with whatever string

Comment: Yep, this makes no sense at all.

Comment: well, I'm just finding around for a good approach. since I'm building and AND-OR tree, I  need to check for  the strings written for user :(

Comment: My mind hurts. Please provide more information if only to unlock me from this twisted view of reality.

Comment: ok, here is.So,  the user writes a  string like this  "(a ^ (b V c))". Now, i have the ability to recognize every  special character like "( , ) , ^ ,~"  but no any string, so i want every string to be recognized as a enum value just for the purpose to construct properly my tree and as a result, do the right evaluation for every operand.

Comment: Salvador, please try to restate your question in a clear and concise manner.  State exactly what goal you are trying to achieve, exactly what you tried to do in order to achieve that goal, and how your attempt failed.  It might help to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Don't explain your question in comments. Please [edit] the question (see the blue *"edit"* link just below the question) to add the missing details.

Comment: sorry for bother guys i could get the solutions, thanks for trying to help me